# Why does Runtime.freeMemory() show more memory after constructing an object?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, profiler

I am trying to figure the size of a hashmap in memory without a profiler. So I did the following:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
lotsOfGC();
long freeMemoryBeforeConstruction = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
System.out.println("memory before = " + freeMemoryBeforeConstruction);
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    String value = "value"+ i;
    map.put(i, value);
}
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
lotsOfGC();
long freeMemoryAfterConstruction = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
System.out.println("memory after= " + freeMemoryAfterConstruction );
```

Where `lotsOfGC` is just:

```
static void lotsOfGC() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            System.gc();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
```

The result I get is:

> memory before =     76083464
>   memory after     =  722062528

Can someone please explain to me why the free memory *after* creating the hashmap is bigger?

**Update:** 
After reading the comment of @Patricia Shanahan I used the total memory and got:

```
memory before        =  76083464  
total memory before  =  96468992  
memory after         = 735235264  
total memory after   = 755367936
```

Comment: it happens everytime? can you confirm?

Comment: @RamanShrivastava:Yes on each run of this trivial program

Comment: How does `Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()` behave? Normally, the in-use memory is the difference between free and total. Allocating an object can trigger getting more memory, increasing total by more than the size of the object.

Comment: @MouseEvent - Are you sure? Check again :)

Comment: There is no guarantee when GC runs, but you are giving good 2 seconds for gc to run before doing freeMemory() call again. I'm not sure, but maybe this is GC which frees memory.

Comment: @RamanShrivastava misread columns, edited post.

Comment: Show us the complete program you ran. In particular, what's `numbers`? And what else is taking up space?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan:Seems you were right. See updated OP

Comment: @user2357112:Numbers is an integer array of size 5.000.000.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan:Add an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The currently allocated memory is the difference

```
Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()
```

Allocating an object, especially a large one, may require the JVM to obtain additional memory from the operating system. That is a relatively expensive operation, so it is more efficient for the JVM to request memory in large chunks. When it obtains more memory than the current allocation requires, both total memory and free memory will increase.

Comment: Would this be different than `Debug.getMemoryInfo()`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I don't know. What package is the class `Debug` in?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky In that case, I definitely don't know.